# Getting the list of Facebook calendars on iOS 6

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk, ekeventkit

When iterating through the list of native iOS EKCalendars is there any way to tell that a specific calendar is a from Facebook? The one you see in the "Facebook" section in native iOS calendar app.

I see those calendars with "type:EKCalendarTypeCalDAV" and "type:EKCalendarTypeBirthday" for calendar.source.sourceType but that's not enough because some other non-Facebook calendars may be of the same sourceType. The titles are also not the same as in the native app: calendar named "Calendar" is named actually "Facebook Events".

Here is the log:

```
// "Facebook Events" calendar
2012-12-27 12:19:30.357 [3335:907] Calendar: type:EKCalendarTypeCalDAV title:Calendar Source: title:CalDAV type:EKSourceTypeCalDAV
2012-12-27 12:19:30.367 [3335:1703] Event: Test event on Facebook

// "Birthdays" calendar
2012-12-27 12:19:30.443 [3335:907] Calendar: type:EKCalendarTypeBirthday title:Birthdays Source: title:Other type:EKSourceTypeBirthdays
2012-12-27 12:19:30.709 [3335:1703] Event: Friend's 1 Birthday
2012-12-27 12:19:30.710 [3335:1703] Event: Friend's 2 Birthday
```

I can't use SDK's EKCalendarChooser because I need to customize it's table view and view some other event sources.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14661337/322548) to a related question, it's not possible to determine whether a specific calendar is a facebook calendar without using private API.