# How to determine that an EKCalendar is a Facebook calendar?

Tags: ios, eventkit

Given any `EKCalendar`, how can I check if this calendar is a Facebook calendar? A Facebook calendar can be the Facebook events calendar or the Facebook birthdays calendar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to tell whether a specific calendar is a facebook calendar without using private API.
I've filed a bug report during the beta of iOS 6 and an Apple engineer told me they'd fix it for the final release, but it turns out they didn't...

You can, however, test if a specific event is a facebook event:

```
BOOL isFacebookEvent = [[event.URL host] hasSuffix:@"facebook.com"];
```

This does *not* work for facebook birthday events, though!

Comment: Thanks!! Do you have any clue how to know whether a birthday calendar is from Facebook? Or is there no way to know...? I have seen for example the app "Week Calendar" do this properly.

Comment: No, I don't know of a legal way to do that. In our app we display birthdays the same no matter where they come from, so we don't have to deal with that problem. "Week Calendar" clearly uses some private API in order to create attendees for events and a lot other stuff, I assume they just use the private API to determine whether it's a facebook calendar, too.

Comment: Can you tell me the private API way of determining whether a calendar is a Facebook calendar? Sometimes Apple does approve calling private API's, if there really is no other way to do it. For example, my app got approved when I called the "source" property of a calendar on iOS 4 (source was made not made public until iOS 5).

Comment: There are two interesting methods: 1) -isFacebookSource in EKSource.h: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EKSource.h and 2) -isFacebookBirthdayCalendar in EKCalendar.h: https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EKCalendar.h

Comment: Note that the two 'interesting' methods are private api calls, your app could be rejected for using them. It's weird but it seems that there is no legal way of getting this info right now... (just pointing it out)

Comment: Well, Tom is aware that these are private API calls: `Can you tell me the private API way of...` But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There is still no public API in EventKit for this, but there is a workaround using only public methods.

Each calendar has a color property: ekCalendar.CGColor

The Facebook event calendar's color is Facebook Blue, so by comparing the rbg components of the calendar color it is possible to determine a calendar is *most likely* from Facebook.

I wrote a swift extension to UIColor to check if a given color is Facebook Blue (complete with helper functions to make the UIColor rgb function more swift like)

```
extension UIColor {

    struct rgbComponents {
        var red : CGFloat
        var green : CGFloat
        var blue : CGFloat
        var alpha : CGFloat
    }

    func toComponents()->rgbComponents {
        var r:CGFloat = 0
        var g:CGFloat = 0
        var b:CGFloat = 0
        var a:CGFloat = 0

        var components : rgbComponents

        if self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a) {
            components = rgbComponents(red: r, green: g, blue: b,  alpha: a)
        } else {
            components = rgbComponents(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)
        }

        return components
    }

    func isFBBlue()->Bool {
        let c = self.toComponents()
        let result = c.red == 0.18823529779911041
                        &&  c.green == 0.39215686917304993
                        &&  c.blue == 0.7137255072593689
                        &&  c.alpha == 1.0
        return result
    }
```

Comment: My experience is that the color of the calendar is not consistent at all. I tried subscribing to the Facebook feed right now, and the color I got was the default calendar blue rather than Facebook blue. I'd say checking if the calendar title contains `Facebook` is probably a bit safer.

Comment: @StefanFisk - this works if the calendar is added via the standard iOS Facebook integration (it's live in my app in the app store and works consistently for my users). If you're adding it as a 3rd party calendar then your results may vary.